# Can't get the ID of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the ID of a button but I can't seem to get it but rather getting the ID of the div which isn't what I want.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container container-about container-login">
    <div id="white-container" class="white-container about-text2 bottom-padding-fortypx">

      <p id="availableTitle" class="text-center avail-title">Available</p>
      <p id="acceptedTitle" class="text-center accept-title">Accepted</p>

      <div id="availableJ" class="contractor-dash-div available-j"></div>
      <div id="acceptedJ" class="contractor-dash-div accepted-j"></div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    i++;
    $('<div>', {
      id: 'available' + i,
      class: "avail-accept-jobs-div margin-bottom-twentypx"
    }).appendTo('#availableJ');
    $('#available' + i).append('<div class="delete-job initial-hidden"><p class="text-center font-weight-bold"><b>X</b></p></div>');

    // Populating the available list
    $('#available' + i).append('<p class="customer-name partial-name">Name: ' + partialName + '</p>');
    $('#available' + i).append('<p class="customer-name full-name initial-hidden">Name: ' + name + '</p>');
    $('#available' + i).append('<p>Date: ' + date + '</p>');
    $('#available' + i).append('<p>Time: ' + time + '</p>');
    // Get this buttons ID
    var but = $('#available' + i).append('<div class="accept-job-button text-center"><p>Accept</p></div>');
    but.id = keys;

    // I understand this is getting the id of the div but the button is essentially a div
    $("div").click(function() {
      alert(this.id);
    });
```

**My question:**

How am I able to get the actual ID of the button which is actually a div?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You want to get the ID of a button, not a div... But your buttons are divs.  Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: @david I edited my question and added a comment above the area I'm trying to get the id of

Comment: So you want the ID of the element you select with this?: `$('#available' + i)`  Um, that ID would be `'available' + i`  It's still not clear at all what the issue is here.

Comment: I think the problem is that "this" does not refer to the div tag. And furthermore I have tried to solve this problem creating a key to a div, however there is an easier way.  Rather than concatenating the div name to a key you can use the prefix "data-" attribute method to create your own attributes in html. http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Yeah, when I go by what I currently have and I click on the 'button' area it will give me back available1, available2, etc. but I actually want the id I'm adding via but.id = keys (keys is pulled form elsewhere). Essentially, I want to get the div when I click on the div with a class of accept-job-button.

Comment: The div with class accept-job-button is where the actual ID is that I need and not the one generated by 'available + i'

Comment: @mur7ay: What is `keys`?  Is it a valid ID?  What is `but`?  Is it the element you expect it to be?  Does setting its ID like that work?  What is the resulting state of the DOM after you do that?  In the click handler, what is the element being clicked?  You have divs within divs and are attaching a click handler to *all* divs.  Maybe you should attach it to *specific* divs?  Are you able to reduce the problem to something specific that can be demonstrated, either in a jsFiddle or in a Snippet here in the question?

Comment: @david yeah, it definitely works. I've updated my question to include an image. In the console you can see that there is an ID which is generated from 'keys'. Keys is coming from Firebase db.

Comment: @mur7ay: Define "works".  Are you actually setting an `id` attribute on the DOM element?  Or just an `id` property on a JavaScript object?  Which are you actually expecting to happen?  It sounds like you're expecting some kind of automatic persistence in the DOM from a jQuery object, but that's simply not the case.  If you want to store something in the element, you have to eplicitly do that.  Perhaps you want to set `.prop('id', keys)`?  Or a data attribute?

Answer (score 0):

this should be the element that fired the event.

you could also respond to the button's click event, directly, instead of waiting for it to bubble up to the div.

if you want the button ID, you can add it as an attribute to the divs firing the event.

if you add matching "btnID" data attributes to the divs and their button, you can get back what you need (in the same attribute) when the user clicks on the div or its button.

BTW, is the value of keys being updated somewhere? if not, it appears you will allow "shared" ID values.

Answer (score 0):

I misread the original question.  If you want to select a child element it is as follows.

```
$("div > .accept-job-button").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```